# How should I define a function that return reference to a pointer? (reference to pointer vs pointer to pointer)

Tags: c++

I want to implement the following function: delete a node of certain value in a binary search tree. I want to do it by two steps: 1.find the node of the value 2.delete the node.

```
//Definition for a binary tree node.
struct TreeNode
{
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};
```

To simplify the problem, assuming that the node to be deleted is a leaf, so we can delete it directly.

I have implemented the search function which returns the reference to the pointer of treenode, so I can change the tree structure directly without the need to track the parent node. But it doesn't work(the node is not deleted).

```
TreeNode *&searchBST(TreeNode *&root, int val)
{
    if (!root)
        return root;
    if (root->val == val)
        return root;
    else if (root->val > val)
    {
        return searchBST(root->left, val);
    }
    else
    {
        return searchBST(root->right, val);
    }
}
```

I have also implemented the search function which returns the pointer to pointer of treenode and it works.

```
TreeNode **searchBST(TreeNode *&root, int val)
{
    if (!root)
        return &root;
    if (root->val == val)
        return &root;
    else if (root->val > val)
    {
        return searchBST(root->left, val);
    }
    else
    {
        return searchBST(root->right, val);
    }
}
```

The full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Definition for a binary tree node.
struct TreeNode
{
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};
TreeNode *&searchBST(TreeNode *&root, int val)
{
    if (!root)
        return root;
    if (root->val == val)
        return root;
    else if (root->val > val)
    {
        return searchBST(root->left, val);
    }
    else
    {
        return searchBST(root->right, val);
    }
}
TreeNode *deleteNode(TreeNode *root, int key)
{
    TreeNode *node = searchBST(root, key);
    if (!node)
        return root;
    node = NULL;
    return root;

}
int main()
{
    TreeNode n1(1), n2(0), n3(2);
    n1.left = &n2;
    n1.right = &n3;
    TreeNode *res = deleteNode(&n1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

The code that works:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Definition for a binary tree node.
struct TreeNode
{
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};
TreeNode **searchBST(TreeNode *&root, int val)
{
    if (!root)
        return &root;
    if (root->val == val)
        return &root;
    else if (root->val > val)
    {
        return searchBST(root->left, val);
    }
    else
    {
        return searchBST(root->right, val);
    }
}
TreeNode *deleteNode(TreeNode *root, int key)
{
    TreeNode **node = searchBST(root, key);
    if (!node)
        return root;
    *node = NULL;
    return root;
}
int main()
{
    TreeNode n1(1), n2(0), n3(2);
    n1.left = &n2;
    n1.right = &n3;
    TreeNode *res = deleteNode(&n1, 2);
    if (res->right != NULL)
        cout << res->right->val << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of "it doesn't work" ? If there are compiler errors you should include them in the question

Comment: seems to be fine here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Y9TTkNGig1rQ0GLe

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It can be compiled but the node is not deleted.

Comment: how do you know? There is no output...

Comment: I use vscode debugger

Comment: the problem is not the search method, but your `deleteNode`. `node` is a local variable in that method, assigning `NULL` to it wont have any effect on the tree

Comment: actually now I am wondering how you came to the conslusion that the other version of `searchBST` "works"...

Comment: you can also try:     if (res->right != NULL) cout << res->right->val << endl;

Comment: the problem with this question is that you made one step too far. You should try to explain better what you observed and why you think there is a problem. The question in the title does not require an answer, because your way of returning a reference to a pointer is fine.

Comment: also read about [mcve]. I know your code is a complete example, but it requires more than compiling and running it to see where/what is wrong with the code

Comment: I have edited the question, you can see the code that works now.

Comment: again: it is the `deleteNode` that makes the difference. `*node = NULL;` is somthing very different than `node = NULL;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have one more question: how can I free the space of the node I deleted?   ```delete *node``` doesn't work.

Comment: what is the meaning of "doesn't work" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I define a function that return reference to a pointer?

The way you wrote `TreeNode *&searchBST(TreeNode *&root, int val)` is fine. The premise of your question is wrong: What makes the difference between your working version and the non-working one is not the `searchBST` but `deleteNode`.

Here:

```
TreeNode *deleteNode(TreeNode *root, int key)
{
    TreeNode *node = searchBST(root, key);
    if (!node)
        return root;
    node = NULL;
    return root;

}
```

`node` is a local variable and assigning `NULL` to it has not effect whatsoever on the actual tree.

On the other hand here:

```
TreeNode *deleteNode(TreeNode *root, int key)
{
    TreeNode **node = searchBST(root, key);
    if (!node)
        return root;
    *node = NULL;
    return root;
}
```

`node` is a pointer to the actual pointer you store in the tree. Hence you can dereference it to assign to the pointer in the tree.

> how can I free the space of the node I deleted?

You don't !

> delete *node doesn't work.

Why do you want to use `delete` ? You never used `new`, hence you should also not use `delete` to free the memory. In main:

```
int main()
{
    TreeNode n1(1), n2(0), n3(2);
    //...
}   // <---
```

`n1`,`n2` and `n3` use automatic storage and get detroyed when they go out of scope (ie when `main` returns, at `<---`).

Comment: "node is a local variable and assigning NULL to it has not effect whatsoever on the actual tree."   Does that means node is a local variable so it can't be set to reference of a non local variable?

Comment: @RickLi maybe `TreeNode *& node = searchBST(root, key);` would work, but I am reluctant to give further advice, because I am not used to handwritten tree implementations, I'd probably use some standard container, because I am certain that I would get my own implementation horribly wrong

Comment: @RickLi in other words: yes,  you can declare a reference locally that references the node in the tree, but in your code you make a copy of `node`

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand it now